# Prevent iPad UIAlertView from dismissing when clicked outside of it?

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertview, dismiss

Is it possible to prevent the default nature of the **iPad** not iPhone UIAlertView so that when a person clicks outside the bounds of the UIAlertView it will not dismiss? Currently you can click anywhere on the screen and it will just dismiss but I can not have this feature because the user has to click something inside the alert view otherwise my application will not run right and it will crash!

So is there any way to change this default behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to show a view that blocks the screen and then call the UIAlertView.

So now you have your view, the blocking view and the UIAlertView in front.

When you clic the UIAlertView option you also dismiss the blockingView.
This blocking View is like a loading View but without a spinner.

Comment: There must be an easier way/documented to do this? Are you 100% sure?

Comment: I'm sure that works.
Otherwise it's weird that the native UIAlertView is not working as you need. I tried that for iPad and it works fine you can't touch out of bound of the UIAlertView.
I'm using this code:
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm cancel" message:@"Are you sure?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil] autorelease] show];